# No versions available for > javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:[3.0, 4.0) within specified range

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, maven-3, datanucleus

I am trying to enhance my Google App Engine project, and I keep getting this error. It was working fine before I had to re-install my OS on my machine and now it complains about this:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5:enhance (default-cli) on project
>   codex-gae:  Execution default-cli of goal
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5:enhance failed: Plugin
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.5 or one of its dependencies could
>   not be resolved:  Failed to collect dependencies for
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.5 (): No versions available for
>   javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:[3.0, 4.0) within specified range -> [Help 1]

Here is the relevant stanza from my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <api>JPA</api>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and I checked in my `~/.m2/repository/` and the `.jar` file is there:

```bsh
[jhr@Jarrods-Mac-Pro] [~/.m2/repository/javax/jdo/jdo-api/3.0.1]

-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff   196K Mar 14 23:18 jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff    40B Mar 14 23:18 jdo-api-3.0.1.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff   7.7K Mar 14 23:18 jdo-api-3.0.1.pom
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff    40B Mar 14 23:18 jdo-api-3.0.1.pom.sha1
```

**Any suggestions why this isn't finding the dependencies?**

Answer (score 1):

So Maven has lost the plot. Delete any maven-metadata-* files (likely in directory above) and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I added the enhance task to the official supported appengine plugin.  You might want to give that a shot instead.  It was just added, so any feedback is well appreciated.  https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/

Comment: My request would be that every page that talks about maven + appengine has to talk about maven + the eclipse plugin + appengine.  Talk about what maven settings corresponding to what GUI settings, what you can do from one and not the other, etc.